# Using gradient angle in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement to create gradient bg like

[image]

with css code

```
.rectangle {
  height: 864px;
  width: 384px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(220.25deg, #2BB88B 0%, #07909B 35.17%, #035762 100%);
}
```

I tried with

```
LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: const <Color>[
            Color(0xFF2BB88B),
            Color(0xFF07909B),
            Color(0xFF035762)
          ],
              /*stops: [
            0,
            0.35,
            0.1
          ]*/)
```

but it doesn't work as expected. Also I have tried with SweepGradient, which also not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try giving it the 'end' property?

end : Alignment.bottomRight or end : Alignment.bottomLeft,

```
LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end : Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: const <Color>[
        Color(0xFF2BB88B),
        Color(0xFF07909B),
        Color(0xFF035762)
      ],
          /*stops: [
        0,
        0.35,
        0.1
      ]*/)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try, what about percentages(0%, 35.17%, 100%) from `linear-gradient(220.25deg, #2BB88B 0%, #07909B 35.17%, #035762 100%)`?

Comment: Percent equivalent is 'stops' already given by you in the code.

Comment: Is that correct? Note that I replaced `0, 35.17, 100` with `0, 0.35, 0.1`...

Comment: Stops are List of values from 0.0 to 1.0 that represent fractions along the gradient.

Comment: Stops in your case should be 0, 0.35, 1.0. Please refer to SDK https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html